# How to rewrite the URL for an addon domain for a single page?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress site at stonycreekgallery.com.au which has redpeppergallery.com.au as an addon domain (correction: '**parked domain'**, sorry).

I want visitors to browse the site primarily as stonycreekgallery.com.au, but whenever they visit the single page http://stonycreekgallery.com.au/red-pepper-gallery/ I want the URL rewritten as redpeppergallery.com.au.

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982476/hypens-in-domain-name-of-htaccess-rewrite) (unanswered) and have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?redpeppergallery.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/red-pepper-gallery/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /red-pepper-gallery/ [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?redpeppergallery.com.au$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ red-pepper-gallery/ [L]
```

These rules are currently active on the domain.

Any pointers for me?! TIA, Tim

---

Edit: Some clarification...

- there is only one site, run on wordpress site
- the links for for redpeppergallery are set in WordPress to point to redpeppergallery.com.au
- redpeppergallery is a parked domain / domain alias (above i mistakenly referred to it as an addon)
- redpeppergallery.com.au should go directly to http://stonycreekgallery.com.au/red-pepper-gallery/

The following does half the job - it takes redpeppergallery directly to the correct page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?redpeppergallery.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/red-pepper-gallery/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stonycreekgallery.com.au/red-pepper-gallery/ [L]
```

The second part of the task is: when on the page stonycreekgallerycom.au/red-pepper-gallery/ (only this page): display the URL as redpeppergallery.com.au.. this is what I'm unsure of... I've since tried:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   ^stonycreekgallery.com.au/red-pepper-gallery/?$         [NC]
RewriteRule   http://redpeppergallery.com.au/  [R=301]
```

I'm expecting to hit a loop sooner or later, but it hasn't happened yet :) variations i've tried of the last snippet have no effect...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root for the **stonycreekgallery.com.au** domain:

```
Redirect 301 /red-pepper-gallery http://redpeppergallery.com.au/
```

If you don't want to redirect, but want the browser's URL address bar to remain at **stonycreekgallery.com.au** then it's going to depend a bit on your configuration.

If both domains are parked at the same document root, meaning for example `http://stonycreekgallery.com.au/` and `http://redpeppergallery.com.au/` are both served from the directory `/something/www/root`, then you'd do this in the document root's htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?stonycreekgallery.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^red-pepper-gallery/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

Otherwise, if one document root is inside the other, meaning for example, `http://stonycreekgallery.com.au/` is served from the directory `/something/www/root` but `http://redpeppergallery.com.au/` is served from the directory `/something/www/root/gallery` then you'd do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?stonycreekgallery.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^red-pepper-gallery/(.*) /gallery/$1 [L]
```

If the two domains are served from completely separate document roots, you'll need to use the `[P]` flag, but that will only work if you have mod_proxy loaded:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?stonycreekgallery.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^red-pepper-gallery/(.*) http://redpeppergallery.com.au/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: thanks Jon Lin, the first snippet looks like the kind of thing I'm after.. but it creates a loop!  I've elaborated on my question above...

Comment: @memeLab If you don't want the URL to change in the address bar, the 2 hosts will need to either be in the same document root, or the `stonycreekgallerycom.au` document root would need to be a subdirectory in the other. Otherwise, do you have `mod_proxy` turned on?

Comment: actually, i _do_ want the URL to change on the /redpeppergallery/ page _only_... there is only one directory (WP install).  I don't think I've got mod_proxy (can't find 'proxy' in phpinfo.php).  Thanks for your time!